# get data by same day with wherebeetween

Tags: php, laravel

Helo, i want to get all data by same date like
$a = 07-12-2022
$b = 07-12-2022

but, in this code i cant get all data when i insert same date on my parameter

this is my code

```
 $request->validate(
        [
            'tanggal_awal' => 'required',
            'tanggal_akhir' => 'required'
        ],
        [
            'tanggal_awal.required' => 'Tanggal awal tidak boleh kosong!',
            'tanggal_akhir.required' => 'Tanggal akhir tidak boleh kosong!',
        ]
    );

    $tanggal_awal = $request->tanggal_awal;
    $tanggal_akhir = $request->tanggal_akhir;

    if ($tanggal_awal and $tanggal_akhir) {
       $pengeluaran = Pengeluaran::select('*')
        ->from('pengeluaran')
        ->whereBetween('pengeluaran.tanggal', [$tanggal_awal, $tanggal_akhir])
        ->get();


        $totalpengeluaran = Pengeluaran::whereBetween('tanggal', [$tanggal_awal, $tanggal_akhir])->sum('jumlah');
    } else {
        $pengeluaran = Pengeluaran::latest()->get();
    }
    return view('pengeluaran.cetak_pengeluaran', compact('pengeluaran', 'totalpengeluaran', 'tanggal_awal', 'tanggal_akhir'));
```

Comment: So when $a and $b are the same value, you are getting no results? What is your expected result?

Comment: @msmahon i want to get all data when i input in same day like start date = 07-12-2022 and end date = 07-12-22

Comment: So just ignore the condition when they are the same?

Comment: @msmahon i cannot ignore it broo. because its important too :(((

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Maybe N69S has the answer.

Answer (score 0):

your `tanggal` is a datetime field, when you use a date to compare against it, it will automatically take the time `00:00:00` so anything between `07-12-2022 00:00:00` and `07-12-2022 00:00:00` are the results having exactly that date time.

You can use `where DATE(tanggal) BETWEEN`

```
 $pengeluaran = Pengeluaran::select('*')
        ->from('pengeluaran')
        ->whereRaw('DATE(pengeluaran.tanggal) BETWEEN ? and ?', [$tanggal_awal, $tanggal_akhir])
        ->get();
```

or simply add the time for one of the dates

```
 $pengeluaran = Pengeluaran::select('*')
        ->from('pengeluaran')
        ->whereBetween('pengeluaran.tanggal', [$tanggal_awal, $tanggal_akhir." 23:59:59"])
        ->get();
```